# Is there any financial rating of electronic trading platforms?

Tags: trust, financial

There are too many different online stores and paid services in the Internet! Some are big and popular, other aren't.

I search for some universal financial rating of electronic trading platforms or, may be, statistics database, that contains history of the work of an online store with bank cards and electronic currencies? This statisctics can be provided by VISA/MasterCard or PayPal, for example.

It can contain the number of *successfully performed operations, the duration of payment acceptance*, but the most importantly: *the percentage of canceled payments, open disputes and litigation*.

I would like to have some tool for assessing the financial reliability of a particular store (I can research their PageRank or Trust Score, but it isn't enough) to distinguish between a good, safe market and scamware.

Comment: This is why PCI-DSS exists. No ratings, no statistics, just required compliance. It's not clear to me what risks you want to assess? A scamware site will have a great transaction history and great scores.